# Is the Azure SQL VM is required after importing a large TFS collection to Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, migration

As per the document, the SQL login has to be deleted or password has to be rotated post import. My question is, do we even need the VM after we successfully import? Can we terminate the Azure SQL VM after importing the TFS collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the TFS instance has been imported into Azure DevOps, you can delete all the resources created for the migration.

This includes any VM's, Storage accounts etc.